Excessive Log Writing in rsyslog After Module Configuration
After adding the following modules to the /etc/rsyslog.d/ directory, the rsyslog keeps rapidly writing logs to the disk, causing the messages and command.log files to grow quickly with extensive logs.
Here is the updated configuration:
[root@rockey2 rsyslog.d]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/cmd.conf
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /var/log/command
$InputFileTag secure-logs
$InputFileStateFile secure-state
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor
local6.* @@192.168.56.103

[root@rockey2 rsyslog.d]# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/message.conf
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /var/log/messages
$InputFileTag messages-logs
$InputFileStateFile messages-state
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor
local6.* @@192.168.56.103

The cmd.conf file captures every command executed on the Linux system, as defined by the PROMPT_COMMAND. Additionally, in the rsyslog.conf file, I have added the following configuration:
local6.* /var/log/commands.log
When I delete the message.conf file, rsyslog continues to insert the usual logs. However, after adding the message logs, rsyslog generates an excessive amount of logs.
Here is a sample from the command.log file:
Dec 26 05:21:10 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:10 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:10 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:09 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:09 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:09 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:09 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:09 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:08 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:08 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:08 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:08 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:58 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:57 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:56 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:55 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:54 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:53 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:52 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:51 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:50 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:49 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:48 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:47 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:37 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:37 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:37 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:36 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:35 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:20:35 rockey2 messages-logs De

And here is a sample from the messages log file:
Dec 26 05:21:42 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:42 rockey2 messages-logs 
Dec 26 05:21:32 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:31 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:31 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:31 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:30 rockey2 messages-logs 
Dec 26 05:21:30 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:30 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:29 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:29 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:29 rockey2 messages-logs 
Dec 26 05:21:29 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:29 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:29 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:28 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:28 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:28 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:28 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:28 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:28 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:27 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:27 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:27 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:27 
rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:27 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:26 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:26 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:26 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:26 rockey2 messages-logs 

Dec 26 05:21:26 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:26 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:25 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:24 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:24 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:24 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:24 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:24 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:23 rockey2 messages-logs 
Dec 26 05:21:23 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:23 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:22 rockey2 messages-logs Dec 26 05:21:22 rockey2 messages-logs
 Dec 26 05:21:22 rockey2 messages-logs

Additionally, I ran the configuration validation command:
[root@rockey2 log]# rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 8.2310.0-4.el9, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: module 'imfile' already in this config, cannot be added [v8.2310.0-4.el9 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]

On the server side, both the messages and command.log files have been increasing rapidly, even though I don't have any modules configured in the rsyslog.conf file on the server side:
# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.* /var/log/boot.log
local6.* /var/log/commands.log

:syslogtag, isequal, "messages-logs:" /var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%-messages.log
& stop

$template remote-incoming-logs, "/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%.log"
*.* ?remote-incoming-logs


Can anyone help me resolve this issue on the Linux machine?
